# how to call a method when exception occur's inside thread

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have thread which calls a method and if any exception occurs it returns to the catch block of that thread.

later, then i like to call a handler or toast message to display the exception but i couldn't call it to display an error.

what should i have to do to solve the problem, any idea.

thanks in advance.

```
private void onSaveDialog() {       

    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setTitle("mApprove Advantage");
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.mapprove1);
    dialog.setMessage("Theme setting is in progress...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(5000);     
                synchronized (this) {
                onsave();
            }
                dialog.cancel();
                onSetting();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.cancel();
                wrongurl=true;
                onFinishDialog1();
                System.out.println("url wrong");

            }

        }           
    }.start();  
    }

private void onFinishDialog1(){
    if(wrongurl){
        wrongurl=false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "URL not Available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Comment: "but i couldn't call it to display an error." - why?

Comment: post your code what you have tried till now?

Comment: i don't know, thread doesn't allow to call any method or handler when it get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {                
          @Override
          public void run() 
            {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(5000);     
                synchronized (this) {
                onsave();
            }
                dialog.cancel();
                onSetting();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.cancel();
                wrongurl=true;
                onFinishDialog1();
                System.out.println("url wrong");

            }
          }
 });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for showing toast message from Thread as:

```
   // your code here
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Your_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            dialog.cancel();
            wrongurl=true;
            onFinishDialog1();
           // show your message here
            Toast.makeText(Your_Activity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

          }
     });
   }
```